# How to get this script to return numbers 0-9 instead of 1-10

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to get numbers 0-9 to shuffle into a random order. EX: 2,4,0,1,3,5,9,7,8,6... Currently it starts at 1 instead of 0.
This is what I'm working with - (my knowledge of js is min.)

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="Javascript">
function pick(n, min, max){
    var values = [], i = max;
    while(i >= min) values.push(i--);
    var results = [];
    var maxIndex = max;
    for(i=1; i <= n; i++){
        maxIndex--;
        var index = Math.floor(maxIndex * Math.random());
        results.push(values[index]);
        values[index] = values[maxIndex];
    }
    return results;
}
function go(){
    var running = true;
    do{
        if(!confirm(pick(10, 0, 9))){
            running = false;
        }
    }while(running);
}

</script>
```

Thanks for the input...

Comment: `for(i=0; i <= n; i++){` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be more beneficial to create more functions here, for readability and easier debugging.

```
// Creates the array [min, min+1, ..., max-1, max]
function createRange(min, max) {
  var range = [];
  while (min <= max) {
    range.push(min);
    min++;
  }
  return range;
}

// Fisher-Yates Shuffle from http://bost.ocks.org/mike/shuffle/
// but you can replace this with your own shuffler if you want
function yatesShuffle(array) {
  var m = array.length, t, i;
  while (m) {
    i = Math.floor(Math.random() * m--);
    t = array[m];
    array[m] = array[i];
    array[i] = t;
  }
  return array;
}

// Pick `n` numbers from the range `[min, ..., max]`.
// `n` must be less than or equal to `(max - min)`.
function pick(n, min, max) {
  var range = createRange(min, max);
  var shuffled = yatesShuffle(range);
  return shuffled.slice(0,n);
}

function go(){
    var running = true;
    do{
        if(!confirm(pick(10, 0, 9))){
            running = false;
        }
    }while(running);
}
```

Comment: That's nice ! But this `n` argument seems pretty senseless since you (and the OP) arbitrarily would take the upper or lower part of the full range if `n` isn't equal to the length of the range. **EDIT:** my bad, I skipped your `.slice()` line. But then why build the full range when you could work on a smaller set ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. `pick(3,50,100)` could respond with `[94, 52, 79]`. And, `pick(10, 50, 52)` responds with like `[51, 52, 50]`. It only picks `n` up to the numbers available to pick from...

Comment: Yes, sorry I skipped your `.slice()` part, but then do you get something building the full range when you could work on a smaller set ?

Comment: Because the in-place sorting is the fastest in the worst-case scenario where n is equal to the full range. Follow the link in the code comments to bostocks explanation.

Comment: That worked, Thank You. I haven't done any scripting/coding since my apple 2e - So it's very confusing. By the way any tips on how to return the value to a div